# Python - pywinauto iface_value.GetValue() Not working, is it because the window selected has no such attribute?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am automating c# based application in which some web page embedded. And I am trying to get data value from table of the page with using dlg_list.iface_value.GetValue(),error occurs as follows,

```
D:\app\python\lib\site-packages\comtypes__init__.py", line 275, in getattr
 fixed_name = self.map_case[name.lower()]
 KeyError: 'getvalue'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:/app/pyprojects/smart/Patient_Registry/Go2Calling.py", line 9, in dlg_list.iface_value.GetValue()
 File "D:\app\python\lib\site-packages\comtypes__init__.py", line 277, in getattr
 raise AttributeError(name) AttributeError: GetValue
```

dlg_list is one of records that could be highlighted with .draw_outline(), I was trying to get the value of the record.

Pywinauto has no GetValue() any more?

March 24 2020 update:

```
row1 = dlg.child_window(title="name row 0").wrapper_object()
dir(row1)
D:\app\pyprojects\smart\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/app/pyprojects/smart/Patient_Registry/Triage.py
['__abstractmethods__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__',
 '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__',
 '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__',
 '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__', '_abc_impl', '_as_parameter_', '_cache',
 '_calc_click_coords', '_control_types', '_create_wrapper', '_element_info',
 '_needs_image_prop', '_select', 'actions', 'appdata', 'backend',
 'can_be_label', 'can_select_multiple', 'capture_as_image', 'children',
 'children_texts', 'class_name', 'click_input', 'client_to_screen', 'close',
 'collapse', 'container', 'control_count', 'control_id', 'descendants',
 'double_click_input', 'drag_mouse_input', 'draw_outline', 'element_info',
 'expand', 'friendly_class_name', 'friendlyclassname', 'get_expand_state',
 'get_properties', 'get_selection', 'handle', 'has_keyboard_focus',
 'has_title', 'iface_expand_collapse', 'iface_grid', 'iface_grid_item',
 'iface_invoke', 'iface_item_container', 'iface_range_value',
 'iface_scroll_item', 'iface_selection', 'iface_selection_item',
 'iface_table', 'iface_table_item', 'iface_text', 'iface_toggle',
 'iface_value', 'iface_virtualized_item', 'iface_window', 'invoke',
 'is_active', 'is_checked', 'is_child', 'is_collapsed', 'is_dialog',
 'is_enabled', 'is_expanded', 'is_keyboard_focusable', 'is_selected',
 'is_selection_required', 'is_visible', 'maximize', 'menu_select',
 'minimize', 'move_mouse_input', 'parent', 'press_mouse_input', 'process_id',
 'rectangle', 'ref', 'release_mouse_input', 'right_click_input', 'root',
 'select', 'selected_item_index', 'set_focus', 'texts', 'top_level_parent',
 'type_keys', 'verify_actionable', 'verify_enabled', 'verify_visible',
 'wait_for_idle', 'wheel_mouse_input', 'window_text', 'windowclasses',
 'writable_props']
```

Avery： `iface_value` is there, but when I try  `dlg.child_window(title="name row 0").iface_value.GetValue()` full error message was like this,

```
D:\app\pyprojects\smart\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/app/pyprojects/smart/Patient_Registry/Triage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\app\python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 275, in __getattr__
    fixed_name = self.__map_case__[name.lower()]
KeyError: 'getvalue'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/app/pyprojects/smart/Patient_Registry/Triage.py", line 35, in <module>
    dlg.child_window(title="name row 0").iface_value.GetValue()
  File "D:\app\python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 277, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: GetValue

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I also tried `dir(var.wrapper_object().iface_value)`, no `GetValue` in the list, `CurrentValue` seems to meet my requirement.

Comment: I can assume the ValuePattern is not supported for this element, but in this case it will raise `NoPatternInterface` exception. Please return `.iface_value` to a variable and call `dir(var)` to list all available attributes.

Comment: I have added to dir(var) but I can see following key-values in Inspect Window:Value.Value: "Jack Donald" \n LegacyIAccessible.Value: "Jack Donald"

Comment: tried another element, it returns **  File "D:/app/pyprojects/smart/login.py", line 44, in <module>
    edit0.iface_value.GetValue()
AttributeError: 'EditWrapper' object has no attribute 'iface_value'**

Comment: `dir()` shows methods for `WindowSpecification`. Please call `.wrapper_object()` first, then call `dir(wrapper)`.

Comment: It's important to post the full error message. Especially for `AttributeError`. I guess current error message is not full.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I updated the post, not sure if this could provide sufficient info again. my only purpose is to take advantage of Inspect tool, where only LegacyIAccessible.Value( or Value.Value) available I can use to get the subject's value. Anyway thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

Well, `ValuePattern` and `LegacyIAccessiblePattern` are different. If you run `Inspect.exe` in "UI Automation" mode and see legacy pattern is supported for the element, you can use wrapper object method `.legacy_properties()` which return the dictionary of legacy properties. For now these properties can't be used as keywords in `.child_window(...)` specification (will be implemented in next major release).

`ValuePattern` support means that you need `.iface_value.CurrentValue` or wrapper method `.get_value()`.