# How to check if Progress Bar is completed in Pywinauto

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

I want to check if the progress bar is completed and if it is then exit my while loop, so I have this for the condition to check should the loop exits:

```
app.Form1.child_window(auto_id="ProgressBar1").get_value == app.Form1.child_window(auto_id="ProgressBar1").max_value
```

This always return false even if the progress bar shows it's completed. Can someone advise me what's wrong? I also tried

```
if app.Form1.child_window(auto_id="ProgressBar1").get_value == '100%'
```

but `app.Form1.child_window(auto_id="ProgressBar1").get_value` returns something like <pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x00000225270C49D0> so I can't check for the value that way.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is get_value a function? If so what is the output of `app.Form1.child_window(auto_id="ProgressBar1").get_value()`

Comment: get_value() gives me the following error: AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'get_value' were found

Comment: Try app.Form1.child_window(auto_id="ProgressBar1").legacy_properties()['Value'] == "100%"

Comment: Got this error message:  File "LMS_Automation.py", line 34, in <module>
    if app.Form1.child_window(auto_id="ProgressBar1").legacy_properties()['Value'] == '100%':
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 180, in __call__
    raise AttributeError("Neither GUI element (wrapper) " \
AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'legacy_properties' were found

Comment: I believe from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783649/python-pywinauto-iface-value-getvalue-not-working-is-it-because-the-window child_window can't be used with legacy_properties

Comment: Is it possible to have your application to do some tests with Pywinauto Recorder? If not, you can try by yourself. Hover the progress bar as in the video tutorial in https://pywinauto-recorder.readthedocs.io/

Comment: @KevinYan `child_window` is just a window specification (please read the Getting Started Guide first about this concept similar to locators in Selenium). It means your progress bar is not found. Please use `app.Form1.dump_tree()` to see all identifiers. So you can copy-paste correct `child_window` specification from `dump_tree()` output for your element.